# android text view not updating

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-c2dm, android-2.2-froyo

i have a problem with updating my textview.
i am making a c2dm app. the messages i send are being recieved by the device (as i have put the message to display in the notifcation bar. also i have many logs that state a message has been received). however once i click on a message within the notification area to open up my view it only shows my 1 message. e.g i send a message, then i want to send another message only the first message shows.

i have found out i may need an `onNewIntent` however i'm not sure if i have gone around it in the correct manner.

```
 public class MessageReceivedActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();            

        if (extras != null) {
            String message = extras.getString("payload");
            if (message != null && message.length() > 0) {
                TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
                view.setText(message);
            }
        }

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    }
     @Override
     protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {             

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();                

            if (extras != null) {
                String message = extras.getString("payload");
                if (message != null && message.length() > 0) {
                    TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
                     setIntent(intent);
                    view.setText(message);    
                }
            }               
//         setIntent(intent);          
     }
}
```

my layout is activity_result which contains only 1 textview
my text view is called result
and payload is the message i send from my server

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Tuffy,as i known you require `android:launchMode="singleTop"` for `MessageReceivedActivity`  `AndroidManifest' or `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` if you starting  this Activity using `startActivity()`

Comment: already thought of that. my launch mode is single top boss

Comment: ok then use `Intent intent2=getIntent();
String str=intent2.getData();` instead of `Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();`

Comment: i get this error on getData("payload"); "The method getData() in the type Intent is not applicable for the arguments (String)"

Comment: String str = getIntent().getStringExtra("payload", "");

Comment: nope. still got the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for all those with this problem.
i had a look on another stack overflow question heres the answer.
in message receiver inside createNotification add this

```
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,intent, 
            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

dont forget the flag at the end that cancels the current view

Answer (score 0):

[Update Textview from function Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282001/update-textview-from-function-android)
[how to change text in Android TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300169/how-to-change-text-in-android-textview)

Hope they can help.
Is there a reason for not using edittext for these kind of situations? I'm new in this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to lookout at your notification ids. You send messages, but all of them have the same notification id. You should somehow increment the notification id.

Comment: its not that. it only displays messages that have been received the first time the app has been opened. i can see the message in the notification however doesnt update my textview

Answer (score 0):

in onNewIntent() method, you should use setIntent(intent) before Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();  or the extras is null

and setContentView(R.layout.activity_result) is not necessary in onNewIntent()

Comment: thats a negative. not working.
i tried:
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
//   setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);
         setIntent(intent);
   Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
   
   if (extras != null) {
    String message = extras.getString("payload");
    if (message != null && message.length() > 0) {
     TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
     view.setText(message);

    }
   }

Answer (score 0):

in Acitity A:

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent();  
        mIntent.setClass(mContext, MessageReceivedActivity.class);  

        mIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);  

        mIntent.putExtra("payload", "fdfsfnj");  
        mContext.startActivity(mIntent);
```

in Acitity MessageReceivedActivity  :

```
    @Override  
        protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent)  
        {  

            String message  = intent.getData();  
            //Or you can use
            String message  = getIntent().getStringExtra("payload", ""); 
super.onNewIntent(intent);  
        }
```